# iterated click on href link list

Tags: python, selenium

I want to iterate through href links and click on each one. My problem is that I cannot extract href, because it is not help me, when I click it i get an empty page.  I should click directly on list of buttons.

There are total 21 nodes, hrefList consist of 21 items.

Here is example of html :

```
<div class="inner25">
<a href="https://www.ida.org.il/?categoryId=96318&itemId=236252">כרטיס רופא ></a>
</div>

<div class="inner25">
<a href="https://www.ida.org.il/?categoryId=96318&itemId=238647">כרטיס רופא ></a>
</div>
```

My code is :

```
hrefList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[contains(text(), 'כרטיס רופא')]")
for link in hrefList:
   link.click()
```

The link of site is :https://www.ida.org.il/?pageType=19&langId=1&paramIds=%2Con_321%2Con_322%2Con_354%2Con_355%2Con_320&scope=&parameterSearch=

In every square you see the doctor. i want to click on each of them.

I found that loop open first link and then failed. What can be a problem?

```
I tried also this code:
            for href in range(1,3):
                hrefList[href].click()

First link it open, and then failed.
This is an error :
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 78, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 499, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Comment: It will get great if you can share details of page in English & text which you want to click , take screen shot & put it in question

Comment: Also your xpath (".//a[contains(text(), 'כרטיס רופא')]") returns empty on home page of website you have shared

Comment: Your xpath is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Use this xapth it returns 21 nodes of your website

```
//a[contains(@href, 'https://www.ida.org.il/?categoryId=96318&itemId')]
```

This code in Java. You have to come back to main page and locate element

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String URL="https://www.ida.org.il/?pageType=19&langId=1&paramIds=%2Con_321%2Con_322%2Con_354%2Con_355%2Con_320&scope=&parameterSearch=";
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(URL);
List<WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'https://www.ida.org.il/?categoryId=96318&itemId')]"));
System.out.println("Total links: "+links.size());
for (int i=0;i<links.size();i++) {
links.get(i).click();
System.out.println(i+"Current URL is: "+driver.getCurrentUrl());
driver.navigate().back();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
links=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'https://www.ida.org.il/?categoryId=96318&itemId')]"));
}   
driver.close();

}
```

Comment: right, i know that size of the hrefList  is 21 nodes, and that's what i want. But when i run loop, it opens the first link and then failed.

Comment: Okay can i give u code in Java as i don;t know too much about python, also you have to come same page. for click on another link

Comment: Okay, i will be happy. but maybe the problem with browser or something like that. I use chrome. I attached another code i tried, and the error i got. please see it.

Answer (score 0):

Beginner issue.You can find a lot of questions related to stale element exception.

You should never do actions that are changing the page in a loop using a list of already found objects, else you will get stale element since the element is not attached to the DOM.

You should save all `href`s values in a list, then in your loop you should do the find element based on the saved href value and call click on the found element.

If the page changes/reloads you need to find the element again.